# How to write this differential operator - Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

i'm trying to implement certain algorithm, and i need to write a differential operator in matrix form. The paper i'm following presents the next operators

$$ A_1 =\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left( g(x,y) \frac{\partial }{ \partial x}\right)$$

$$A_2 =  \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \left( g(x,y) \frac{\partial }{ \partial y}\right) .$$

These operators are suposed to act over a scalar field $\phi$

and it says that both of them can be written in form of a tridiagonal matrix, and if gives the elements of the tridiagonal and define the elemnts [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0uEm.png)  .

The thing is i can't figure it out, how they reach that expression and why it doesn't have any indication of the fact that $g$ depends on $x$ and $y$ .

Any way... i  need a way to write this operators as tridiagonal matrix, in order to apply an unconditionally stable scheme for the numerical method...

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.